# VM image with ready-to-use Rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtualbox

So... I've been trying to start developing Rails, and I'm having a horrible time setting up my environment.

Installed Ubuntu 12.10 in a VM. Installed RVM. Installed Ruby 1.9.3. Installed Rails. Then Rails console didn't work because I didn't have readline, and I had to start futzing with rvm commands from [here](https://rvm.io/packages/readline/) and from a Stack Overflow thread, only to get numerous incomprehensible errors.

And that's just me trying to get off the ground and start running. Please oh please, isn't there a ready VirtualBox VM file with a machine preconfigured for development work?

Comment: Rifle around Github on their gist site. Many of us keep some kind of Vagrant (easy-peasy vm manager) provisioning scripts up there. If I didn't work in a primarily *nix based environments I would have one ready for you. For example this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2963576) should do some shell provisioning on a vagrant instance for a pre-built Rails env.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this: https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box

Hoping it's going to help; consistent with Branden's comment above.

Comment: Just to note, this says explicitly it is for development OF rails, not of rails web applications.

Answer (score 7):

If you would just like one built for you go to: https://railsbox.io

Tutorial will set you you with vagrant/rails much like the other answers are talking about. I haven't used it but it looks solid:
https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development

You could also simply use a remote vm that is setup and available anywhere:

https://c9.io/

There are other similar options out there.

I have used both of them and they function excellently for this purpose, they also troubleshoot well on google because you have multiple people using the same environment. If you are new to Rails/Ruby and are unfamiliar with using a nix environment I highly suggest this route. You will also be able to access them more or less anywhere through a browser.

I know it is rather an old thread but since it came up so easily in a search and the answer wasn't entirely satisfactory when I had found it previously I thought I would broaden the list of options.